# Kendo UI Grid with 2-dimensional JSON data structure

Tags: json, multidimensional-array, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Most examples of the Kendo UI Grid displays 1-dimensional data grids. I have 2 dimensions in the data I get. One "name" and one collection of child-objects. The number of child-objects in the collection is random and should expand dynamically. I.e. some times the object might contain 10 items (all rows has the same amount though).

I have created an example of what I need to achieve:

```
+----------+--------+--------+-----+--------+-------+
|   Name   | Sweden | Norway | USA | Russia | China |
+----------+--------+--------+-----+--------+-------+
| Jesper   |     10 |      2 |  33 |      4 |     5 |
| Yngve    |      2 |     33 |   4 |      5 |    99 |
| Snoddas  |     10 |      2 |  33 |      4 |     5 |
| Herkules |     10 |      2 |  33 |      4 |     5 |
+----------+--------+--------+-----+--------+-------+
```

The data structure would look something like this, all just dummy data so typos may exist:

```
var data = {
    resultContainer: [
        { name: "Jesper", countries: [{ nr: 2, c: "Sweden" }, { nr: 2, c: "Norway" }, { nr: 32, c: "USA" }, { nr: 34, c: "China" }] },
        { name: "Yngve", countries: [{ nr: 55, c: "Sweden" }, { nr: 1, c: "Norway" }, { nr: 23, c: "USA" }, { nr: 43, c: "China" }] },
        { name: "Herkules", countries: [{ nr: 55, c: "Sweden" }, { nr: 4, c: "Norway" }, { nr: 7, c: "USA" }, { nr: 7, c: "China" }] }
    ]
};
```

Just throwing it in the Kendo UI will of course not work:

```
$(".grid-container").kendoGrid({
    DataSource: {
        data: data.resultContainer
    },
    height: 550,
    groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    }
});
```

Doing like this will render a first column with the name (correctly), and one second column with the object [object Object].

What's the best way of achieving this? Do I have to change the data-structure that I receive?

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't so hard actually. I just manually create a column array before the Kendo UI Grid initialization... Something like this:

```
        var columns = [];

        // Add dealer column
        columns.push({
            field: "name",
            title: "Name",
            width: "100px"
        });

        // Add columns dynamically
        for (var i = 0; i < data.resultContainer[0].countries.length; i++) {
            var entryIndex = "countries[" + i + "]";
            columns.push({
                field: entryIndex,
                title: (1 + i).toString(),
                width: "auto"
            });
        }
```